# c++ regex grab all the text between 2 tags including new lines and spaces

Tags: c++, regex

I am trying to grab all the texts between all the ul tags in an html file using regex. This pattern works fine with inline tags like li but it won't work if text includes multiple lines. Thanks

```
   int main()
     {

        string fname = "test.html";
        file_to_string fts(fname);
        std::regex item_names ("<ul>(.*?)</ul>");
        string s = fts.get_string();
        std::regex_token_iterator<std::string::iterator> rend;
        std::regex_token_iterator<std::string::iterator> b ( s.begin(), s.end(), item_names );


    while (b!=rend)
        {cout<<"\""<< *b++<<"\" ;"<<endl;}
     return 0;}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your regex is correct but you need to use s-flag (dot matches new line). But it is not supported in basic c++ flavor thus you may tweak it to cover \s\S instead of dot(.) which means you will accept non whitespace and whitespace characters!

Sample Source ( [run it here](https://ideone.com/fqK6mp) ) :

```
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string input =R"(This text is <ul>pretty long, but will be 
      concatenated into just a single string. 
       The disadvantage is that you have to quote 
      each part, and </ul>newlines must be literal as 
      usual.)";

    string regx = R"(<ul>([\s\S]*?)<\/ul>)";
    smatch matches;
    if (regex_search(input, matches, regex(regx)))
    {
        cout<<matches[1]<<"."<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Cwda4c/1)

Comment: The question refers to C++, not C#

Answer (score 2):

I suggest running it like this with a common modified dot lazy pattern with a:`<ul>([\s\S]*?)<\/ul>`
Since tags are not case-sensitive we should use the `i`|`icase` case-insensitive flag.

[Sample code:](https://ideone.com/gpd4DA)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <regex>
int main()
{
   std::string html = "<ul><a href=\"http://stackoverflow.com\">SO</a></ul> "
                      "<ul>abc</ul>\n";
   std::regex url_re(R"(<ul>([\s\S]*?)<\/ul>)", std::regex::icase);
   std::copy( std::sregex_token_iterator(html.begin(), html.end(), url_re, 1),
              std::sregex_token_iterator(),
              std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

Comment: We could also use a tempered greedy token that should show better performance [`<ul>(((?!<\/ul>).)+)<\/ul>`](https://ideone.com/GbPUKK) esp. with large strings.